# ¿Por qué se me muestra una consulta en php que no está en mi base de datos Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas tardes, tengo dos campos registros en mi base de datos que son los siguientes:

> Tabla vuelos

[image: tabla de vuelos]

Y al verlo en mi documento `vuelos.php` se ve de esta manera:

[image: tabla en documento]

Como se logra apreciar, se crea un registro fantasma sin dato alguno (el primero), ya he comprobado en mi documento que no esté puesto de manera individual por lo que sé que el error está en mi consulta y no logro verlo. Agradezco de antemano si me pueden guiar.
Este es el código que utilizo en `vuelos.php` para mostrarlos

```
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","conce");
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM vuelo, origen, salida, aviones WHERE vuelo.cod_origen = origen.cod_origen AND vuelo.cod_salida = salida.cod_salida AND vuelo.cod_avion = aviones.cod_avion");
do { ?> <div class="booking-history">
                                <div class="booking-info clearfix">
                                    <div class="date">
                                        <label class="month">Codigo Vuelo</label>
                                        <label class="date"><?php echo $row['cod_vuelo'];?></label>
                                        <label class="day">Hora: <?php echo $row['hora'];?></label>
                                    </div>
                                    <h4 class="box-title"><i class="icon soap-icon-plane-right takeoff-effect yellow-color circle"></i>Desde <b><?php echo $row['nombre_origen'];?></b> hasta <b><?php echo $row['nombre_salida'];?></b><small>Avión asignado: <?php echo $row['nombre_avion'];?> </small></h4>
                                    <dl class="info">
                                        <dt>Fecha del vuelo</dt>
                                        <dd><?php echo $row['fecha'];?></dd>
                                        <dt>Puerta asignada</dt>
                                        <dd><?php echo $row['gate'];?></dd>
                                    </dl>
                                    <button class="btn-mini status">PROGRAMADO</button>
                                </div>


                        </div>
                        <?php
}
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))

    ?>

                        </div>

<?
mysqli_close($con); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El detalle esta en que usas el "do-while", ya que se ejecuta al menos una vez y en tu caso en la primera iteración no tienes un registro que mostrar; al iterar el resultado de una consulta es más recomendable usar "while".

Aquí una referencia del uso ciclos en PHP:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping.asp

Y la posible solución al registro "fantasma" que mencionas:

```
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","conce");
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM vuelo, origen, salida, aviones WHERE vuelo.cod_origen = origen.cod_origen AND vuelo.cod_salida = salida.cod_salida AND vuelo.cod_avion = aviones.cod_avion");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) 
{ 
?> 
     <div class="booking-history">
          <div class="booking-info clearfix">
              <div class="date">
                   <label class="month">Codigo Vuelo</label>
                   <label class="date"><?php echo $row['cod_vuelo'];?></label>
                   <label class="day">Hora: <?php echo $row['hora'];?></label>
              </div>
              <h4 class="box-title"><i class="icon soap-icon-plane-right takeoff-effect yellow-color circle"></i>Desde <b><?php echo $row['nombre_origen'];?></b> hasta <b><?php echo $row['nombre_salida'];?></b><small>Avión asignado: <?php echo $row['nombre_avion'];?> </small></h4>
              <dl class="info">
                    <dt>Fecha del vuelo</dt>
                    <dd><?php echo $row['fecha'];?></dd>
                    <dt>Puerta asignada</dt>
                    <dd><?php echo $row['gate'];?></dd>
              </dl>
              <button class="btn-mini status">PROGRAMADO</button>
         </div>
    </div>
<?
}
php mysqli_close($con); 
?>
```